# Rails - Paperclip ROLLBACK due to associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, paperclip, paperclip-validation

I have 3 `models`. The `question`, `answer` and `photo`. I am using `paperclip` to `save` images. `Questions` and `answers` can have `multiple images`.

However, I get `ROLLBACK` when saving images for `answer` model. I don't get `ROLLBACK` when saving images for `question` model. I think I have a problem with `model associations`.

```
#photo model
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question 
  belongs_to :answer

  has_attached_file :image :path => ":rails_root/public/img/:filename", validate_media_type: false
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image
end

#answer model
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :question
 has_many :photos
end

#question model
class Question < ApplicationRecord  
  has_many :answers
  has_many :photos
end
```

My Controller :

```
p.answers.each do |a|
  new_answer = q.answers.create(body: a[:body])
  if a[:images]
    a[:images].each do |e|
      new_answer.photos.create(image: URI.parse('www.abc.com/'+e))
    end
  end
end
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Check if photo if valid. Build your `Photo` record with `photo = new_answer.photos.build(image: URI.parse('www.abc.com/' + e))` and then check `photo.valid?` and `photo.errors`.

Comment: Is there an error message next to the rollback? How do the log entries look like for that request?

Comment: I don't have validations : `do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :image` . I only get :    `(0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/home_controller.rb:418 `

Comment: change your code to `new_answer.photos.create!(image: URI.parse('www.abc.com/'+e))` and look for photo.errors and paste them in post

Answer (score 0):

Since rails 5 the `belongs_to` associations are by default required.

There are two possible solutions, either write

```
belongs_to :question, optional: true
```

in your `Photo` model, or, as you are saving them through the nested association (a bit like a nested-form), you have to clearly indicate which association is the inverse of which.

So in your answer class, specify the inverse of the `:photos` association

```
 has_many :photos, inverse_of: :answer
```

(to allow rails to correctly check that the belongs_to is set correctly)